# Get inner image from HTML Canvas 2D Context

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

Given a canvas 2D context, how do I create an image from specified bounds of an image?

For example, say I have a `context` to a canvas with a height and width of 100 and I want to create a new image from coordinates `25, 25` to `75, 75`.

Comment: Show us what you have tried .Did you do a search of this topic?

Comment: I've searched StackOverflow for a similar question, and I could only find a question that answers this along with a lot of other stuff pertaining to tilesets, so I figured it'd be best to make this its own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `toDataURL()` only can convert the complete canvas into an image you need to clip your image first.

Create a temporary canvas - here's an example wrapping everything up in a re-usable function:

```
function getImageFromRegion(canvas, x, y, w, h) {

    var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');

    tmpCanvas.width = w;
    tmpCanvas.height = h;

    ctx.drawImage(canvas, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
    //ctx.drawImage(canvas, -x, -y);  /// can be used as well..

    return tmpCanvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Now you just call the function:

```
var dataUri = getImageFromRegion(canvas, 25, 25, 50, 50);
```

and your `dataUri` will contain the image only with that region.

If you don't mean `toDataURL()` then just return the `tmpCanvas` instead without calling `toDataURL()` and you can use the new canvas as an image, or simply use the single line with `drawImage()` which is here used with clipping..

Answer (score -1):

You need to use drawImage() function. [More on drawInfo()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)

Comment: That's drawing onto a canvas, not into a new Image. This question is looking for the inverse operation.